# How to run the AngularJS Tutorial from Google?

Tags: angularjs

I've found this to be a very useful tutorial so far, probably one of the best step by step guides ever created for programming as EVERY SINGLE STEP is seen committed via GitHub:

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/the_end

I hit a brick wall towards the middle and I can't host a json object on a Microsoft IIS server I have provided by GoDaddy. I have to edit my web.config file because Microsoft apparently thought it was a great idea to throw a 404 on the URL of a pure JSON object:

http://cinicraft.com/angular/phones/phones.json

So that's a valid URL according to my FTP browser, but yeah I get a 404. Microsoft is brilliant in using the "not found" error exception with a file that exists.

And so I can't really go any further with the tutorial, I've decided to try running the completed version Google has available on GitHub, but I have no idea on how to run this:

```
 ۩/partials/
     ۞/phone-list.html
     ۞/phone-detail.html
 ۩/js/
     ۞/jquery.js
     ۞/controllers.js
     ۞/app.js
     ۞/angular.min.js
     ۞/bootstrap.min.js
 ۩/angular
     ۞/angular-route.js
 ۩/test
 ۩/phones
 ۩/fonts
 ۝/index.html
```

If I just open index.html straight from my finder on Chrome I only see a blank page, how does one run this AngularJS app?

Is node.js required?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the url https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat and Prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Go to `applicationhost.config` file in your IIS `config` folder and add the following where similar mime types are defined

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

If still not allowed go to `<requestFiltering>` section and add the following

```
<add fileExtension=".json" allowed="true" />
```

Comment: I'm using GoDaddy for hosting, where can I find this "applicationhost.config" file? Can I create a new one with a text editor and put it in the root directory?